# How many messages can I send to a queue?

Tags: jakarta-ee, queue

I have a Queue configured in my appserver. Is there a limit on how many messages I can send to the queue?

Comment: I think it depends on the nature of the queue and the server it's running on. Could you provide more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes. Computers have a finite amount of memory, so eventually you'll hit a limit. Without further information (size of data, type of application, JVM memory limits, etc) it's impossible to answer your question more in depth.

Comment: I almost +1ed this, but then there is the possibility that someone consumes fast enough so you don't run out of resources.

Comment: @Waldheinz: is that a fat joke?

Comment: No really a joke, I don't see a problem with putting lots of messages into a queue when it's drained just fast enough. The OP gave very little context so we just don't know if it will work for him or your answer will ultimately be true for his application.

Comment: @Waldeheinz: well see THAT was a joke ;) Yes I get it.